Angular18 and pixi.js hello world
I try to make simple app with pixi.js and ang18.
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 // app!: PIXI.Application;
  title = 'game';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const app = new PIXI.Application();
    let type = "WebGL";
      if (!PIXI.isWebGLSupported()) {
        type = "canvas";
      }

//Add the canvas that Pixi automatically created for you to the HTML document
document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);
PIXI.sayHello('HELLO');
}}


Compilation is well but I got blank page. Could yoy please help me to find answer: why I can't see HELLO text.

You need to 'init' the app after you instantiate the PIXI.Application class
await app.init();

is missing.
-https://pixijs.download/release/docs/index.html
